# React Native Flatlist CellRendererComponent renders all at once?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to make use of CellRendererComponent in Flatlist (rn 0.62) to let the zIndex prop to work, and it does, but all the data is rendered at once.
If I try to set initialNumToRender={number} and windowSize={number}  then it limits the render, but doesn't render after the number set in those props.

```
<FlatList
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  horizontal
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={data}
  CellRendererComponent={renderGanttCell}
  keyExtractor={ganttKeyExtractor}
  bounces={false}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
  initialNumToRender={3}
  windowSize={9}
/>
```

Changing CellRendererComponent to renderItem works without the zIndex, but all the data is lazy rendered.

Any work around to keep CellRendererComponent and lazy render the rest of the data?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but for anyone else (like me) arriving here. React Native VirtualizedList calls CellRendererComponent like so:

```
<CellRendererComponent
    {...this.props}
    style={cellStyle}
    onLayout={onLayout}>
    {element}
    {itemSeparator}
</CellRendererComponent>
```

Your custom CellRendererComponent has to implement at least the onLayout prop:

```
function MyCustomCellRenderer(props) {
    return(
        <View onLayout={props.onLayout}>
            ...etc
        </View>
    )
}
```